# Insert <router-link> into string as computed value in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, computed-properties

I have a use case inside a component where within a description string (contained as text within a [b-card-text Bootstrap Vue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/card#titles-text-and-links) element), I want one particular word to be replaced by an internal link using '` if the user is logged in (as determined by the value of another variable), but if not, then just use the default text. Normally I would use a computed value for something like this, but I can't get it to return just the router link. The text is fairly long, so I don't want to include all of it in the computed value.

Here's what I tried:

```
computed: {
  accountPageLink() {
      return this.authUserIsAccountOwner ?
          '<router-link :to="/account"></router-link>' :
          'Account';
    }
}
```

But that just returns a string, and if I remove the quotes from the link, I get an error saying `Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled` .

Is there a way to do what I want to do with just replacing the one word dynamically in the string?

Answer (score 2):

I normally do this logic in the template.

```js
<router-link v-if="authUserIsAccountOwner" to="/account">Edit Account</router-link>
<template v-else>Account</template>
```

Alternatively, you can pass in this computed HTML into the `v-html` binding of the element:

```js
<div v-html="accountPageLink"></div>
```

If you're pattern matching to find the word(s) you want to replace, you can do that in the computed property and use the `v-html` binding to insert it into your template element.  For example:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-html="linkifiedText"></div>
</div>

<script>
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      someText: 'Lorem ipsum dolor account sit amet',
      authUserIsAccountOwner: true,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    linkifiedText() {
      return this.authUserIsAccountOwner
        ? this.someText.replace('account', '<a href="/account">linkifiedAccount</a>')
        : this.someText;
    },
  }
});
</script>
```